# Flutter - Bottom Overflowed By 230 Pixels Stak Layout

Tags: android-studio, flutter

someone help me please enter image description here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRZbs.jpg

i need the box resized automatically fot the content.

i'm new in flutter any suggestions?

```
bodyWidget(BuildContext context) => Stack(

children: <Widget>[
  Positioned(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5, //Altura del box cone squinas redondeadas
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
    left: 10.0,
    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
    child: Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 130.0, // espacion entre el texto de la descripcion y la foto del producto
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` . Read about it [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html).

Comment: i can't understand this solution, i was tried in this part:    body:
        bodyWidget(context), resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution:**
you usually need to provide a scroll widget on top of your widgets because if you try to open the keyboard or change the orientation of your phone, flutter needs to know how to handle the distribution of the widgets on the screen.

Please review this resource, you can check the different options that flutter provide Out of the box, and choose the best option for your scenario.

[Scrolling](https://flutter.io/widgets/scrolling/)

**Second Option:**

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false
```

That should make the error disappear

You can see through a sample code :

```
appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Create A Parking Slot')),
      body: new Center(
          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 10.0),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Title*"),
          ),
          new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Available Space in Sqft*"),
          ),
          new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Available Space*"),
          ),
          new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Address*"),
          ),
          new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Contact Number*"),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: const Text('Select Your Plan'),
            trailing: new DropdownButton<String>(
              value: "Hourly",
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                print(newValue);
              },
              items:
                  <String>['Hourly', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'].map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            height: 1.0,
            width: width,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          new TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Rate*"),
          ),
          new UploadImage(),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Create'),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 4.0,
            splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            onPressed: () {
              // Perform some action
              //button1(context);
            },
          )

          //
        ]),
      )))
```

Comment: thank you so much, i used you sample code and i can adapt you solution in my code =)